Display data only before the last hyphen in a list of values in an otbi report
There is a column with department name. Department name consists of a name followed by a hyphen, followed by the dept number. In some cases the department name has a hyphen in it as well. So at max, 2 hyphens in a value. I need to create two separate columns, department name and department number.
I was able to separate the department number using a right function since the department number is always 5 numbers. The department name however is what I’m not able to figure out.

Generally, if the number is always 5-digits long then:

the name is the sub-string excluding the last 6 characters; and
the number is the sub-string containing the last 5 characters.

In Oracle, you can use:
SELECT department_name,
       SUBSTR(department_name, 1, LENGTH(department_name) - 6) AS name,
       SUBSTR(department_name, -5) AS department_number
FROM   departments;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE departments (department_name VARCHAR(200));

INSERT INTO departments (department_name) VALUES ('accounting-00001');
INSERT INTO departments (department_name) VALUES ('human-resources-00002');

Outputs:



DEPARTMENT_NAME
NAME
DEPARTMENT_NUMBER




accounting-00001
accounting
00001


human-resources-00002
human-resources
00002



Oracle fiddle

In SQL Server, you can use:
SELECT department_name,
       LEFT(department_name, LEN(department_name) - 6) AS name,
       RIGHT(department_name, 5) AS department_number
FROM   departments;

Which outputs:



department_name
name
department_number




accounting-00001
accounting
00001


human-resources-00002
human-resources
00002



SQL Server fiddle
